# Problems with different complexities on directed and mixed graphs

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request

Some computational problems have different complexity on different graph classes. For instance, 3-edge coloring is NP-complete on cubic graphs but polynomial on cubic bipartite graphs.

> What are the graph problems that have different complexities on directed and mixed graphs.

A mixed graph can have both directed and undirected edges. A perfect answer would be a survey paper of such problems.

Comment: Shortest path, under the assumption that $\mathsf{L\neq NL}$.

Comment: @Ariel I am interested in P, NPI, and NP-complete problems.